# LinqKit Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.InstanceMethodCallExpression2' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression'

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, linqkit

I have a problem with `Expressions`. I have this lambda LINQ query with Entity Framework Core LINQ Provider:

```cs
IQueryable<ProcessValueBase> valuesSubquery;
switch (req.Period)
            {
                case TimePeriodType.Current:
                    valuesSubquery =  dbContext.ProcessValues;
                    break;
                case TimePeriodType.Day:
                case TimePeriodType.Week:
                case TimePeriodType.Month:
                    valuesSubquery = dbContext.NormalizedLogValues;
                    break;
                default:
                    valuesSubquery = dbContext.ProcessValues;
                    break;
            }
var res = dbContext.Rooms.Select(r => new
            {
                RoomId = r.Id,
                ZoneId = r.ZoneId,
                IdealSetpoint = r.Group.Setpoints.First(sp => sp.ClimaticZoneId == dbContext.ClimaticZonesLogs.OrderByDescending(cz => cz.Timestamp).First().ClimaticZoneId).Setpoint,
                Devices = r.Devices
                .Select(rd => rd.Device)
                .Select(d => new
                {
                    Id = d.Id,
                    Name = d.Name,
                    //Setpoint = GetQuery(rd.Device.Id).Average(t=>t.Value)
                    Setpoint = valuesSubquery.Where(GetQuery(req.Period, d)).Average(t => t.Value)
                })
            }
            ).ToList();
```

Then I have a function that deals with the predicate dynamically:

```cs
private  Expression<Func<ProcessValueBase,bool>> GetQuery(string period, DeviceModel device)
        {
            var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<ProcessValueBase>();
            predicate = predicate.And(v => v.TagSettings.DeviceId == device.Id);
            predicate = predicate.And(v => v.TagSettings.TagTypeId == GetSetpointTagTypeId(device.DeviceTypeId));
            predicate = predicate.And(v => v.ClimaticZoneId == dbContext.ClimaticZonesLogs.OrderByDescending(cz => cz.Timestamp).First().ClimaticZoneId);

            var utcTime = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
            switch (period)
            {
                case TimePeriodType.Day:
                    var startOfDay = utcTime.StartOfDay();
                    predicate = predicate.And(v => v.Timestamp >= startOfDay && v.Timestamp < startOfDay.AddDays(1));
                    break;
                case TimePeriodType.Week:
                    var startOfWeek = utcTime.FirstDayOfWeek();
                    predicate = predicate.And(v => v.Timestamp >= startOfWeek && v.Timestamp < startOfWeek.AddDays(7));
                    break;
                case TimePeriodType.Month:
                    var startOfMonth = utcTime.FirstDayOfMonth();
                    predicate = predicate.And(v => v.Timestamp >= startOfMonth && v.Timestamp < startOfMonth.AddMonths(1));
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return predicate;
        }
```

The error that I'm getting is as follows:
[image: exception]

The message is:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.InstanceMethodCallExpression2' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression'.
```

Can anyone suggest what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Julian

EDIT:
As an answer to Svyatoslav Danyliv answer. The exception that it gives me is:

```
The LINQ expression 'DbSet<NormalizedLogValueModel>()
    .Where(n => (v, device) => v.TagSettings.DeviceId == device.Id && v.TagSettings.TagTypeId == SetpointSideViewHandler.GetSetpointTagTypeId(device.DeviceTypeId) && v.ClimaticZoneId == DbSet<ClimaticZoneLogModel>()
        .OrderByDescending(c0 => c0.Timestamp)
        .Select(c0 => c0.ClimaticZoneId)
        .First() && v.Timestamp >= __startOfDay_0 && v.Timestamp < __AddDays_1
        .Invoke(
            arg1: n, 
            arg2: EntityShaperExpression: 
                EntityType: DeviceModel
                ValueBufferExpression: 
                    ProjectionBindingExpression: Inner
                IsNullable: True
        ))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

When `GetQuery(req.Period).Compile()(p,d)`:

```
The LINQ expression 'DbSet<NormalizedLogValueModel>()
    .Where(n => Invoke(__Compile_0, n, [RelationalEntityShaperExpression])
    )' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

Comment: Do you use latest LINQKit version?

Comment: I didn't! I've updated to last version, but the problem persists :(

Comment: I github issue is created: https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit/issues/140

Comment: Will check right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well answer is complicated, but from my experience it is only one way to do that:

Usage:

```cs
var res = dbContext.Rooms
    .Select(r => new
    {
        RoomId = r.Id,
        ZoneId = r.ZoneId,
        IdealSetpoint = r.Group.Setpoints.First(sp => sp.ClimaticZoneId == dbContext.ClimaticZonesLogs.OrderByDescending(cz => cz.Timestamp).First().ClimaticZoneId).Setpoint,
        Devices = r.Devices
        .Select(rd => rd.Device)
        .Select(d => new
        {
            Id = d.Id,
            Name = d.Name,
            Setpoint = valuesSubquery.Where(p => GetQuery(req.Period).Invoke(dbContext, p, d)).Average(t => t.Value)
        })
    }
    ).ToList();
```

New function (it could be compiler errors, not tested):

```cs
private static Expression<Func<DBIContext, ProcessValueBase, DeviceModel, bool>> GetQuery(string period)
{
    Expression<Func<DBIContext, ProcessValueBase, DeviceModel, bool>> predicateTemplate = (dbContext, v, device) =>
        v.TagSettings.DeviceId == device.Id &&
        v.TagSettings.TagTypeId == GetSetpointTagTypeId(device.DeviceTypeId) &&
        v.ClimaticZoneId == dbContext.ClimaticZonesLogs.OrderByDescending(cz => cz.Timestamp).First().ClimaticZoneId;

    var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<ProcessValueBase>();

    var utcTime = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
    switch (period)
    {
        case TimePeriodType.Day:
            var startOfDay = utcTime.StartOfDay();
            predicate = predicate.And(v => v.Timestamp >= startOfDay && v.Timestamp < startOfDay.AddDays(1));
            break;
        case TimePeriodType.Week:
            var startOfWeek = utcTime.FirstDayOfWeek();
            predicate = predicate.And(v => v.Timestamp >= startOfWeek && v.Timestamp < startOfWeek.AddDays(7));
            break;
        case TimePeriodType.Month:
            var startOfMonth = utcTime.FirstDayOfMonth();
            predicate = predicate.And(v => v.Timestamp >= startOfMonth && v.Timestamp < startOfMonth.AddMonths(1));
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    Expression<Func<ProcessValueBase, bool>> lambda = predicate;

    var newBody = predicateTemplate.Body;
    newBody = Expression.AndAlso(newBody, ExpressionReplacer.GetBody(lambda, predicateTemplate.Parameters[1]));

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<ProcessValueBase, DeviceModel, bool>>(newBody, predicateTemplate.Parameters);
}

[Expandable(nameof(GetSetpointTagTypeIdImpl))]
private static long GetSetpointTagTypeId(long deviceTypeId)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

private static Expression<Func<long, long>> GetSetpointTagTypeIdImpl()
{
    return deviceTypeId => deviceTypeId == 180_000 ? 180_002
        : deviceTypeId == 190_000 ? 190_002 : 0;
}
```

And helper class:

```cs
public class ExpressionReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
{
    readonly IDictionary<Expression, Expression> _replaceMap;

    public ExpressionReplacer(IDictionary<Expression, Expression> replaceMap)
    {
        _replaceMap = replaceMap ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(replaceMap));
    }

    public override Expression Visit(Expression exp)
    {
        if (exp != null && _replaceMap.TryGetValue(exp, out var replacement))
            return replacement;
        return base.Visit(exp);
    }

    public static Expression Replace(Expression expr, Expression toReplace, Expression toExpr)
    {
        return new ExpressionReplacer(new Dictionary<Expression, Expression> {{toReplace, toExpr}}).Visit(expr);
    }

    public static Expression Replace(Expression expr, IDictionary<Expression, Expression> replaceMap)
    {
        return new ExpressionReplacer(replaceMap).Visit(expr);
    }
    
    public static Expression GetBody(LambdaExpression lambda, params Expression[] toReplace)
    {
        if (lambda.Parameters.Count != toReplace.Length)
            throw new InvalidOperationException();

        return new ExpressionReplacer(Enumerable.Range(0, lambda.Parameters.Count)
            .ToDictionary(i => (Expression) lambda.Parameters[i], i => toReplace[i])).Visit(lambda.Body);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I've tried this approach, and I had an error `The LINQ expression .... ))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated`

Comment: Post full exception message

Comment: it is too long for a comment, shall I edit your answer?

Comment: Yes, if you can. Otherwise edit question.

Comment: I've edited the question, the answer a couldn't. Thanks

Comment: Try instead of `GetQuery(req.Period).Invoke(p, d)` - `GetQuery(req.Period).Compile()(p, d)`

Comment: Edited the question again

Comment: Another try `GetQuery(req.Period).Expand().Invoke(p, d)`

Comment: The same as the one with `GetQuery(req.Period).Invoke(p, d)`

Comment: Looks like a LINQKit bug. If you prepare github issue with this code, I'll try to fix.

Comment: I've made  an issue in github. Thanks!

Comment: Let's try again. I have added additional parameter `MyDbContext`, I do not know type of your context. `GetSetpointTagTypeId` also needs expanding. Also do not change static to non-static methods.

Comment: @Julian, I have tested it works. No LINQKit bugs, probably you have changed static to non-static - it's important. Updated only parameter index.

Comment: Like written above, it gives compiler error on `return Expression.Lambda<Func<DBIContext,ProcessValueBase, DeviceModel, bool>>(newBody, predicateTemplate.Parameters);` - `Cannot implicitly convert type Expression<Func<ProcessValue, DeviceModel, bool>> to Expression<Func<MyDbContext,ProcessValue, DeviceModel, bool>>`
All code is Copy/Paste from your answer

Comment: When I correct the issue it again gives me an error that I have to rewrite the query

Comment: Corrected types. Yes, it is another problem )) Your query is totally weird for LINQ translator. LINQKit just simplified writing such expressions, but writing correct queries is completely your task.

Comment: Try to comment out which part is problematic. I vote for `First` in both places.

Comment: I still get the error for not translating the query. After all it is getting super complicated as you say this query is wired enough. I'll mark the answer as accepted, because LinqKit does what it is expected to do. Thanks for the support!